# How to sample from a distribution with constraints in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, distribution, torch

I got a simple situation like:

> Generate samples and `log_prob` from an uniform distribution for 2-dim variables (m1, m2) which is satisfying m1~U(5, 80), m2~U(5, 80) with constraint m1+m2 < 100.

```py
from torch import distributions
prior = distributions.Uniform(torch.tensor([5.0, 5.0]),
                              torch.tensor([80.0, 80.0]))
```

I try coding in PyTorch like the above, but I don't know how to construct a [`torch.distribution`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html) with constraint condition. By the way, I see some implementations about [`torch.distributions.constraints`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#module-torch.distributions.constraints) but I can't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved using [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling):

```
d = torch.distributions.Uniform(5, 80)

m1 = 80
m2 = 80

while m1 + m2 >= 100:
    m1 = d.sample()
    m2 = d.sample()
    print(m1, m2)
```

Example output:

```
tensor(52.3322) tensor(67.8245)
tensor(68.3232) tensor(40.0983)
tensor(44.7374) tensor(9.9690)
```